# how to use arrays and sets using postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Could someone help me fix the below code so that it returns all the records that are not in the array being passed to the function? The array contains the pKey values. Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_getProperty(propertiesID integer[])
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$ 

declare mycursor refcursor;


BEGIN


  mycursor   = 'mycursor';

  OPEN mycursor FOR ( select distinct property1, property2
                      from properties
                  where propertyid not in (propertiesID ));


  RETURN mycursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT property1, property2
FROM properties
WHERE NOT propertyid=ANY(propertiesID);
```